# Max Date Minus X Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a date in the database.

I have to choose the maximum date and subtract x days from it.
it should happen according to the expression below I have selected a maximum date but I have to subtract certain days from date

```
DECLARE @MAX_DATE_VB as datetime 
SET @MAX_DATE_VB = (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE, Date_of_drop)) as MAX_DATE
    FROM STORAGE
```

the desired result is to select the maximum date that is in the database but munis x days

Comment: So what is your question? And please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. PS pretty sure you are missing a bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `dateadd` function:

```sql
select dateadd(dd, -1, @max_date_vb) as new_date
```

You may change the second argument for the specific days you need to subtract.

See documentation for usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15